# View with all content created in onDraw inside HorizontalScrollView is not scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/shadow_height"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow_top" />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <dk.somefirm.MyView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </HorizontalScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

the MyView class extends View and creates all its content in its onDraw method. With the added android:fillViewport="true" parameter it now draws the MyView just fine, but scrolling is not working. The MyView is sometimes wider than the screen and should be horizontal scrollable.

I am guessing the reason for this is that the view has no content and thus a width of zero. I have tried to set the width like this in my code:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = getLayoutParams();
lp.width = (int) (TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, ls, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()) * (savingPoints.size() + 1));
setLayoutParams(lp);
```

The width is dynamic so it has to be dependent on the list elements, but it does not help, it is not scrollable.

Any ideas what is wrong here please?

Thank you
Søren

Comment: have you tried putting your view inside some container inside ScrollView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your view inside a linear layout like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@color/white"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/shadow_height"
    android:background="@drawable/shadow_top" />

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <dk.somefirm.MyView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
 </HorizontalScrollView>
```